# how to get image id

Tags: php, javascript

I am creating a list of images dynamically, following is the code

```
<?php
for ( $counter = 0; $counter < $obj1->id; $counter ++)
{ ?>
<tr><td> Week <?php echo($counter+1); ?>
</td><td><?php echo" <a href=\"#hiddenDiv\" rel=\"facebox\";>";?>
<img src="tue.png"/ id="image" value="<?php echo $counter+1;?>" >
</a></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

when the user clicks on the image a form opens. every image represents a week so i need to uniquely identify on which week user is inserting data. i need id of that image through which i can identify a week.
On click at the image following function is called

```
function pc(){
var temp = document.getElementById("image");
alert(temp.value);
}
```

but i am getting "undefined". can somebody help me with this?

Thanks

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have a problem when you get the id it should be like this var temp = document.getElementById("image");

Comment: If you want to use the id passed to the function as the argument to `getElementById`, then you need to lose the quotes ... `getElementById(id)` ...

Comment: Post the generated HTML, not the PHP that generates it. Also, where is the function pc being called?

Comment: <img id="image" src="tue.png" value="hello" onClick="pc()" />

Answer (score 2):

You will notice that I changed the id on the img tag, which means each new image will have the id of the current counter.

I also added an onclick event to the link, and pass in the counter to the js function.

```
<?php
for ( $counter = 0; $counter < $obj1->id; $counter ++)
{ ?>
<tr><td> Week <?php echo($counter+1); ?>
</td><td><?php echo" <a href=\"#hiddenDiv\" onclick=\"pc(<?php echo $counter;?>)\" rel=\"facebox\";>";?>
<img src="tue.png"/ id="<?php echo $counter;?>" value="<?php echo $counter+1;?>" >
</a></td></tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Also, remove the quotes around "id" in your js function:

```
    function pc(id){
    var temp = document.getElementById(id);
    alert(temp.value);
    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you're doing with the template changes to generate a unique id for each image.

Comment: just to make things easy i am doing this                           <img id="image" src="tue.png" value="hello" onClick="pc()"/>
and in the JS function i am doing this
    function pc(){
    var temp = document.getElementById("image");
    alert(temp.value);
    }
it is still not working

Comment: @talhaMalik22 this won't do what you desire. You're creating multiple images with the same id of "image". So in your js function, when you call getElementById("image") it will only return you the first occurrence, not the specific one that they click.

Answer (score -1):

you have to pass id of the tag. like `document.getElementById("image").`

```
function pc(id){
var temp = document.getElementById("image");
alert(temp.value);
}
```

Comment: How does this solve anything?  The OP is generated a bunch of images all with the same ID.  That problem has to be fixed first.